# jQuery load() doesn't work in IE8 & 7

Tags: jquery

I got this code running

```
$j('#nav_menu-2 li li a').bind('click', function(e){ 
    //check when pagination link is clicked and stop its action.
    e.preventDefault();

    //get the href attribute
    var link = $j(this).attr('href');

    $j('#content').load(link + ' #content');
});
```

its working fine in chrome, ff, ie9 but the problems begin with ie8 and ie7.

I searched the web and tried this way

```
$j('#content').load(link + '?' + Math.random()*99999 + ' #content');
```

but its still not working, the content just doesn't show.
[this is the url to the site](http://cana-stone.co.il/site/)

just click the first blue box(arrow 1), and try to change the content the arrow 2 and arrow 3.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was an extra unneeded `</div>` tag inside the html code.
All the modern browsers was able to handle this, but apparently ie8 and 7 just got lost that mess.

Answer (score 2):

This looks wrong:

```
$j('#content').load(link + '?' + Math.random()*99999 + ' #content');
```

Try this instead:

```
$j('#content').load(link + '?' + (Math.random()*99999).toString());
```

And I'm not sure you need that random number, unless you're having problems with cache.

```
$j('#content').load(link);
```

Here's a solution with cache disabled that looks up `#content` in the response, for good measure (untested):

```
$j.ajax({
    url: link,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
        $('#content').html($(data).find('#content').html());
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey thordarson. the #content is there because I need only the #content div from the target, if I'll remove it, it will load the entire html of the page.

Comment: The random part needs to be wrapped with parentheses. `(Math.random() * 99999)`.

Comment: @Mitz Look at my last solution. I edited it to find the #content element. It's still untested though, but should work.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with `' #content'`. It's jQuery functionality (with the space character). The problem is something else, because it generally works in other browsers.

Comment: @thordarson, i changed the code to your suggestion, but the result is the same.. you can see it live now.

Comment: I'm looking at the source, IE8 isn't throwing any errors and I can't find anything yet, but I came across this: `<div class="menu-%d7%aa%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%98-%d7%a6%d7%93-container"><ul id="menu-%d7%aa%d7%a4%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%98-%d7%a6%d7%93" class="menu">` What's up with those names?

Comment: I found the problem. I had extra </div> tag in the html. all the modern browsers was able to handle that, but apparently ie8 and 7 just got lost in this.
I'll keep the Ajax code in there, thank for helping.

This weird IDs are written in Hebrew on server side, I know its wrong and its not gonna be there for long :)

Comment: Alright, glad you solved it. You should post this as an answer and accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

ajax requests are cached in IE8, so just a little magic of

$.ajaxSettings.cache = false;

before the using load function

http://zacster.blogspot.in/2008/10/jquery-ie7-load-url-problem.html

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
Type: Boolean
If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.