# .load not working in IE8 - image

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

Hello I have a problem in making my jQuery work in IE8. I'm not that good in jQuery, but I think I might have localized the problem..

The problem is, when you click on a product you should be seeing a bigger picture of the product, but I don't think it is loading the image in IE8.

This is my jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        $("a.slidein").click(function(){
            var post_url = $(this).attr("href");
            var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");
            $("#post").html("<div style='width:100%; text-align:center;'><h2>LOADING...</h2></div>");

            $("#post").load(post_url);

            window.location.hash = post_id;

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the site:

```
http://kangaroos.dk.web2.redhost.dk/categories/shoes/
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Any errors in your console/developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

Probably same problem as in [jQuery load() doesn't work in IE8 & 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542076/jquery-load-doesnt-work-in-ie8-7)
Looks like your markup is broken - every product in you layout grid is nested within the previous one, and a missing closing tag can break things in IE.

Comment: Well, you gotta look closely at your template to find misplaced tags. A good IDE helps.

Comment: I also saw his problem, but the solution didn't work to me. But maybe I am putting it the wrong way..